# Read records from JSON file in ASP.net Core (v2.1) WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.0

I am new to asp.net core WebApi and I am trying to read data from a valid json file which is saved inside a folder called mydata inside my webapi

/mydata/userData.json

**userData.json:**

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "firstName": "John",
            "lastName": "Doe"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "firstName": "Jane",
            "lastName": "Doe"
        }
}
```

I wrote a web method that takes an input as first name, and returns single user object (first found record incase multiple results).

**UserController.cs:**

```
[Route("user/{firstName}")]  
public User GetUser(string firstName)  
{  
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("~/mydata/userData.json"))
    {
         string json = r.ReadToEnd();
         User item =JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(json);
    }
    var user = User; 
    return user;  
}
```

I am facing the following issues:

1. I am not able to map the file userData.json, i tried Server.MapPath but it looks like its not available, httpcontext also did not work.
2. I do not understand how to return a User Object from this api, which will be used in a react app.

Comment: Your file name is `user.json` but in your `StreamReader` you're trying to read a file with different name `userData.json`. Is that a typo?

Comment: @Izzy that was a typo, I fixed that. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this by making use of `IHostingEnvironment` to get the root path and `Path.Combine()` method. So your controller should look like:

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

    public UserController(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
    {
        _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
    }

    [Route("user/{firstName}")]
    public User GetUser(string firstName)
    {
        var rootPath = _hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath; //get the root path

        var fullPath = Path.Combine(rootPath, "mydata/user.json"); //combine the root path with that of our json file inside mydata directory

        var jsonData = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(fullPath); //read all the content inside the file

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(jsonData)) return null; //if no data is present then return null or error if you wish

        var users = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<User>>(jsonData); //deserialize object as a list of users in accordance with your json file

        if (users == null || users.Count == 0) return null; //if there's no data inside our list then return null or error if you wish

        var user = users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.FirstName == firstName); //filter the list to match with the first name that is being passed in

        return user;

    }
}
```

**Please note:** `IHostingEnvironment` will be removed in the future releases so if you can upgrade your framework then do so, so you can use the recommended `IWebHostEnvironment` type.

Comment: Thanks, I am trying this approach. and getting this error:
- $exception {"Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[App.Models.User]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.\r\nTo fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or ......

I will keep debugging.

Comment: Is this error in derealization happing because JSON file contains a "Users" object that contains a list of users (json file does not directly contains a list) ?

Comment: The `JSON` file content which you included in your question, the syntax was incorrect because you was missing the closing `]`. Before posting my answer yesterday, I added the closing `]` and manage to deserialize without any issues. If you're `JSON` file content has changed, please add it to your question and I will update my answer.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a working demo:

/mydata/userData.json:

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "firstName": "John",
      "lastName": "Doe"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "firstName": "Jane",
      "lastName": "Doe"
    }
  ]
}
```

project structure:

[image]

Model:

```
public class User
    {
        public List<UserModel> users { get; set; }
    }
    public class UserModel
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string firstName { get; set; }
        public string lastName { get; set; }


    }
```

action:

```
[Route("user/{firstName}")]
        public User GetUser(string firstName)
        {
            using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("mydata/userData.json"))
            {
                string json = r.ReadToEnd();
                User item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(json);
                return item;
            }
            return new User();
           
        }
```

result:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

First of all, in asp.net core you are only able (by default) to read data from the wwwroot folder. If you want to change that, then [refer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38406699/16638833).

Second of all, you are trying to read only single object, but in you json file, there are multiple user objects. You can fix this by replacing your code `User item =JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(json);` by this `List<User> items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<User>>(json);`

And finally, as mentioned in comments, when you StreamRead, you reference wrong file... Also it's better if you [reference the file using enviromental variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41552554/16638833)

Hope I helped!

Answer (score 0):

1-) Sample path;

```
StreamReader r = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Suleyman\Desktop\users.json");
```

2-) sample;

```
  public List<User> GetUser(string firstName){}


List<User> item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<User>>(json);
```